# Insert large blob into MySQL database in Node.Js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm using Node.js + express for my backend application, mysql package for DB connectivity. I need to support large file upload and store it into MySQL database. MySQL column type is  longblob.
I've implemented file upload handling with busboy as a stream:

```
  const bb = busboy({ headers: req.headers });
  bb.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
    console.log(`File ${fieldname}, ${file}, ${filename}, ${encoding}, ${mimetype}`);
    file.on('data', data => {
      console.log(`File [${filename}] got ${data.length} bytes`);
    })
    .on('close', () => {
      console.log(`File [${filename}] done`);
    });
  });
```

Is it possible to stream blob contents into SQL insert query instead of reading entire file into memory as JS Buffer?

Comment: I dont know the details of nodejs but in java I prefer connecting inputStream to outputStream of database. In that way you just store it with byte array approach which uses 4096 bytes in process. Just investigate that way and maybe you need to change your database library.